# How to remove/wash away instant glues if fallen in hand

Tags: home, adhesive

When working with instant glues they fall onto my hands and create an unwashable glue spot which is not good in feel, so is there any way I can remove/wash away instant glue.

Answer (score 1):

Super glues which dry instantly can be removed using salon-strength nail polish remover, very high in acetone and used to remove gel finish manicures.  Salon strength and gel removers are almost pure acetone, unlike regular nail polish remover. This will dry your skin if used often and is a very flammable substance so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Use rubbing alochol or nail polish remover. Both work exceptionally well for super glue and other sticky glues.